# i dont cant take the source from my notebook with terraform

Tags: terraform, cloud, task, databricks, databricks-notebook

Regards

I am creating a databricks notebook using terraform cloud. When the notebook code is in the same directory as the tf there is no problem, it finds it right away. But to organize the repository, the notebook must be in another folder and that is where the problem begins that the notebook cannot be found. the folder path is src/notebook/mynotebook.py.
What should I do to correctly reference the route.

could you help me please

options of "source" to can take the notebook

Comment: Please take a look here on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should use %run magic command and run the notebook that you want to reference within the notebook where you want to use the function with code as below

```html
%run ./dir/notebook
```

Link here - https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#use-run-to-import-a-notebook